# Sending vector space to dual is a functor

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

In the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over a field and linear maps between them, the map that sends each space to its dual and linear map to its transpose is a functor, right?

But this doesn't make sense to me.  Call the map $F$, and let $f: V \to W$ and $g: W \to Z$ be linear maps.  So,

$$ F(g \circ f) = (g \circ f)^{*} :Z^* \to V^*$$

needs to be  $F(g) \circ F(f)$ but this is not defined, $F(f) \circ F(g)$ is defined however.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The functor $F$ is a contravariant functor, that is why it reverses composition. Check out the definitions at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.